# Divide columns in pandas with different size dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm facing a little challenge with pandas which i'm having a hard to time figure out.

I have created two dataframes with the following code

```
df5 = dataFrame[['PdDistrict' , 'Category']]
df5 = df5[pd.notnull(df5['PdDistrict'])]
df5 = df5.groupby(['Category', 'PdDistrict']).size()
df5 = df5.reset_index()
df5 = df5.sort_values(['PdDistrict',0], ascending=False)

df6 = df5.groupby('PdDistrict')[0].sum()
df6 = df6.reset_index()
```

This gives me two dataframes. df5 contains how many times a specific category occurs in a given district. e.g.

```
'Category'   'PdDistrict'  'count'
   Drugs       Bayview       200
   Theft       Bayview       200
   Gambling    Bayview       200
   Drugs       CENTRAL       300
   Theft       CENTRAL       300
   Gambling    CENTRAL       300
```

the df6 frame contains the total number of categories for a given PdDistrict.

This gives df6 the following look

```
'PdDistrict' 'total count'
  Bayview        600
  CENTRAL        900
```

Now what I want is that df5 gets to look like this e.g:

```
'Category'   'PdDistrict'  'count'      'Average'
   Drugs       Bayview       200           0.33
   Theft       Bayview       200           0.33
   Gambling    Bayview       200           0.33
   Drugs       CENTRAL       200           0.22
   Theft       CENTRAL       200           0.22
   Gambling    CENTRAL       200           0.22
```

So it's basically taking count from df5 and dividing it by totalcount from df6, but for the same district. How can I do this?

```
res = df5.set_index('PdDistrict', append = False) / df6.set_index('PdDistrict', append = False)
```

The above gives me NaN in Category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `total count` col to your first df and then you can perform the calculation:

```
In [45]:
df['total count'] = df['PdDistrict'].map(df1.set_index('PdDistrict')['total count'])
df

Out[45]:
   Category PdDistrict  count  total count
0     Drugs    Bayview    200          600
1     Theft    Bayview    200          600
2  Gambling    Bayview    200          600
3     Drugs    CENTRAL    300          900
4     Theft    CENTRAL    300          900
5  Gambling    CENTRAL    300          900

In [46]:
df['Average'] = df['count']/df['total count']
df

Out[46]:
   Category PdDistrict  count  total count   Average
0     Drugs    Bayview    200          600  0.333333
1     Theft    Bayview    200          600  0.333333
2  Gambling    Bayview    200          600  0.333333
3     Drugs    CENTRAL    300          900  0.333333
4     Theft    CENTRAL    300          900  0.333333
5  Gambling    CENTRAL    300          900  0.333333
```